# Jxbrowser 6.14.2: Search in Pdf of multiple occurrence word is throwing exception com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException

Tags: jxbrowser

Jxbrowser : I was searching for the text that is having multiple occurrences in pdf opened in Jxbrowser .I clicked enter and I was taken to the first search result but after pressing the enter again ,the jxbrowser thread hangs for 120 seconds and the problem is only reproducible while doing the search in Pdf.

com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException: Response was not received.
2017-07-20 12:35:05,658 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR  -  at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.findText(SourceFile:1033)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in JxBrowser 6.18.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. When i expected to release a new version of JxBrowser in which the above issue is resolved?

Comment: I cannot provide this information at the moment. When a new version with the fix is available for download I will let you know.

Comment: The above mentioned issues is resolved in latest release's of JxBrowser??

Comment: Unfortuntely, still not fixed

Comment: The issue has been fixed in JxBrowser 6.18.